# How to execute an action before loading a page in Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor

I got a Java Webapp project which uses Struts2 as the controller layer. I need to check user's permissions before doing anything (like opening a web page). I have developed an authorization system which is needed to be executed in struts action. So, how is it possible to execute this action before loading of a page? Should I use interceptors?

Comment: I don't get your question. If it must be executed in the Struts action, then execute it in the Struts action. What's the problem?

Comment: See, the problem is I want to execute the action before loading any content of a specific page. This could be the scenario: 1-user enters www.app.com/admin.jsp 2-The permissions should be checked in an action 3-if authorized, the page gets loaded else an error is shown.

Comment: @SJ.Jafari: if you want to implement a authorization system go for a authorization framework like spring-security/JAAS etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You failed to understand the whole point of an MVC framework like Struts. In a MVC app, you should **never** have any link or form pointing to a JSP.

You should **always** point to a URL mapped to the Struts servlet/filter. Then the servlet invokes the appropriate action based on the URL, the action returns the result (the JSP to go to), and Struts forwards to this JSP.

If you point to a JSP directly, then you're bypassing Struts completely. Read http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1999/jw-12-ssj-jspmvc.html

Comment: I think you got me :D, I actually am aware of the whole point of a MVC framework. The thing is, apart from using struts as a controller for forms, I didn't think of using them for links. Thanks anyway, I got my answer.

Comment: If you are not using the struts2-conventions-plugin I would strongly recommend looking at it. You would apply an interceptor and it would enforce that all jsp's in a certain folder would use it.  Then you don't need any xml (well perhaps a little to define your interceptor stack). Point being you just create links without needing to worry about action mappings, conventions will do the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely, you should implement your own interceptor and put it on top of the other interceptors (not necessarily on the top). If you put it on top, it works before your page execution and can change your return value.

For example:

In your struts.xml

```
<interceptor name="security"
    class="com.solekia.common.SecurityInterceptor">
</interceptor>

<interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="security"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="exception" />
...
</interceptor-stack>

<global-results>
    <result name="login" type="redirectAction">Login</result>
    <result name="adminlogin" type="redirectAction">AdminLogin</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</global-results>
```

Your Interceptor:

```
public class SecurityInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor
{
    public static final String CURRENT_USER = "current_user";
    public static final String LOGIN = "login";
    public static final String ADMINLOGIN = "adminlogin";

    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

        Object user = invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession().get(CURRENT_USER); 
        Object action = invocation.getAction();

        if(action instanceof Login)
        {
            return invocation.invoke();
        }
        else if(action instanceof Register)
        {
            return invocation.invoke();
        }
        else if(action instanceof Pro)
        {
            return invocation.invoke();
        }

        if( user == null )
        {
            invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession().clear();
            return LOGIN;
        }
        else
        {
            if(user instanceof User)
            {
                if(action instanceof AdminLogin)
                    return ADMINLOGIN;
            }

            if(user instanceof Admin)
            {
                if(action instanceof ClientPortal)
                    return LOGIN;
            }           

            synchronized(user)
            {           
                return invokeLocal(invocation) ;
            }
        }
    }

    protected String invokeLocal(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception
    {
        return invocation.invoke();     
    }   
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've been making a fundamental mistake pointing to links directly.